# Query with a data frame and a database

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

I'd like to know if it's possible to make a query between a data frame and a database like this :

```
test <-  sqlQuery(ch,"
                  SELECT *
                  FROM table_from_database as A, dataframe as B
                  WHERE  a.id=b.id ")
```

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to specify what kind of database do you have in mind. SQL? Sqlite?

Comment: It's a database with microsoft sql server

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say No. You could query the db and then do the join with the df in R, or (if you have sufficient access to the db) you could upload the df as a table and then do the join there.

Comment: The `sqldf` package should be able to do that, at least with SQLite/MySQL/Postgres: transparently send the data.frame to the database as a temporary table, and run the query in the database (using other tables).

Comment: @joran: Oh ye of little faith.  This is R; of course it can be done!

Answer (score -1):

Use the RODBC package to connect to a MS SQL Server database.

First you need to do some setup.  Open the "Data Sources (ODBC)" application.  (In `Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools`, or search under the Start Menu.)  Add a User DSN (or a System DSN if you have admin rights and want the connection for all users).

Step 1: Give it a name like `MyDataBase` and select the server that it lives on.  The name shouldn't be more than 32 characters or you'll get a warning.
Step 2: Connection details are the same as you would use in SQL Server.
Step 3: Change the default database to the one that you want to connect to.
Finish and test your connection.

Now you get to use R.  It's as easy as

```
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnect("MyDataBase") #or whatever name you gave
query <- "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE x > 10"
results <- sqlQuery(query, channel)
odbcClose(channel)
```

---

If you are feeling fancy or hate wizards, you can set up the ODBC connection by writing registry entries.  Apologies for the big code chunk.

```
#' Reads the Windows registry
#'
#' Wrapper for readRegistry that replace environment variables.
#' @param ... Passed to readRegistry
#' @return A list of registry keys.  See \code{readRegistry}.
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' key <- "Software\\ODBC\\ODBCINST.INI\\SQL Server"
#' hive <- "HLM"
#' read_registry(key, hive)
#' readRegistry(key, hive)
#' }
read_registry <- function(...)
{
  ans <- readRegistry(...)
  lapply(
    ans,
    function(x)
    {
      rx <- "%([[:alnum:]]+)%"
      if(is.character(x) && grepl(rx, x))
      {
        env_var <- stringr::str_match(x, rx)[, 2]
        x <- gsub(rx, Sys.getenv(env_var), x)
      }   
      x
    }
  )
}

#' Add an ODBC data source to the Windows registry.
#' 
#' Adds an ODBC data source to the Windows registry.  
#' 
#' @param data_source_name String specifying the name of the data source to add.
#' @param database The name of the database to use as the default.
#' @param database_server The name of the server holding the database.
#' @param type Type of connection to add.  Either ``sql'' or ``sql_native''.
#' @param permission Whether the connection is for the user or the system.
#' @return Nothing.  Called for the side-effect of registering ODBC data sources.
#' @details A key with the specified data source name is created in 
#' ``Software\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI'', either in ``HKEY_CURRENT_USER'' or 
#' ``HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'', depending upon the value of \code{permission}.  
#' Four values are added to this key.  ``Database'' is given the value of the  
#' \code{database} arg.  ``Server'' is given the value of the 
#' \code{database_server} arg. ``Trusted_Connection'' is given the value ``Yes''.
#' ``Driver'' is given the value from the appropriate subkey of 
#' ``HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBCINST.INI'', depending upon the type.
#' Another key with the specified data source name is created in
#' ``Software\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\ODBC Data Sources''.
register_odbc_data_source <- function(data_source_name, database, database_server, type = c("sql", "sql_native"), permission = c("user", "system"))
{
  #assert_os_is_windows()

  #data_source_name <- use_first(data_source_name)

  permission <- match.arg(permission)
  type <- match.arg(type)  

  #Does key exist?
  odbc_key <- readRegistry(
    file.path("Software", "ODBC", "ODBC.INI", fsep = "\\"), 
    switch(permission, user = "HCU", system = "HLM")
  )
  if(data_source_name %in% names(odbc_key))
  {
    message("The data source ", sQuote(data_source_name), " already exists.")
    return(invisible())
  }

  hive <- switch(
    permission,
    user   = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER",
    system = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
  )
  key <- shQuote(
    file.path(hive, "Software", "ODBC", "ODBC.INI", data_source_name, fsep = "\\")
  )
  odbc_data_sources_key <- shQuote(
    file.path(hive, "Software", "ODBC", "ODBC.INI", "ODBC Data Sources", fsep = "\\")
  )

  type_name <- switch(
    type,
    sql = "SQL Server",
    sql_native = "SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
  )
  driver <- read_registry(
    file.path("SOFTWARE", "ODBC", "ODBCINST.INI", type_name, fsep = "\\"), 
    "HLM"
  )$Driver

  system0(key)
  system0(key, "/v Database /t REG_SZ /d", database)
  system0(key, "/v Driver /t REG_SZ /d", shQuote(driver))
  system0(key, "/v Server /t REG_SZ /d", database_server)
  system0(key, "/v Trusted_Connection /t REG_SZ /d Yes")
  system0(odbc_data_sources_key, "/v", data_source_name, "/t REG_SZ /d", shQuote(type_name))
}

#' Wrapper to system for registry calls
#' 
#' Wraps the \code{system} function that calls the OS shell.
#' @param ... Passed to \code{paste} to create the command.
#' @return The command that was passed to system is invisibly returned.
#' @note Not meant to be called directly.
system0 <- function(...)
{
  cmd <- paste("reg add", ...)
  res <- system(cmd, intern = TRUE)
  if(res != "The operation completed successfully.\r")
  {
    stop(res)
  } else
  {
    message(res)
  }
  invisible(cmd)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I already know how to connect and make a query to the database.
I wast just wondering if I could make a query between a table of the Db and a data.frame.
It's seem I need to download the table or to upload the data.frame into the Db.

Comment: OK, the question was a little ambiguous.  I have no idea why you'd want to use SQL to mix data from completely different places.  Do what Joran suggested.

Comment: I was wondering if the OP ever found a solution?  I am having the same issue - I have a SQL DB with read access, and a local datafile that I want to use to subset data from the SQL DB on patient_id.  I can't create a #temp table in the SQL Database because I have no bulk priveleges.  If I could merge an R dataframe directly with the SQL DB I could do it.